# MSI uninstall not executing Installer class tagged with [RunInstaller]

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer

We are developing a MSI installer solution (based on VDPROJ, unfortunately) that will install an instance of our server application. The installer has all been designed to support the concept of installing multiple instances. This means we've written a small utility that takes a 'stub' MSI and then outputs a configured MSI with a unique Product Code, Product Name etc amongst other things. The Product Code is updated in both the Property table and Summary Information stream.

Everything seems to work fine on the install step. Our two test instances, AcmeCorp and ZurgCorp, are installed side-by-side just fine. Their Windows Services are all registered and function as expected.

However, we have encountered a very strange issue when it comes to uninstalling one of these instances. It doesn't matter which instance we uninstall first. But which ever one we choose, the uninstall will proceed very quickly - but so quickly that it actually misses out calling our .NET Installer subclass (tagged with RunInstaller and being called by the CustomAction).

The uninstall will be 'successful' and the MSI will be gone from Add/Remove Programs list. But the Windows Service remains behind because the MSI uninstaller never run our assembly to remove it!

Now if we go ahead and uninstall the second instance as well, this one will uninstall just fine including the Windows Service.

So what on earth is going on here?

It smells to me of some form of reference counting. But where? We've followed the book on this when it comes to making sure the Product Code's are different. Maybe there is something we are missing to do with Component Id's?

Thanks.

Comment: I have now run the uninstall process with full debug tracing enabled and it does indeed appear to be related to the Component Id's.

I can see on the uninstall where the Windows Service is not removed that the debug trace many entries like this:

"Disallowing uninstallation of component: {long guid here} since another client exists"

So it appears the MSI, despite having a different Product Code and even Upgrade Code, is actually conflicting with the MSI of the other instance through the Component Id's.

I wonder what the solution is here, other than regenerating the Component Id's?

Comment: Could you please list concrete properties you are changing? ProductCode, UpgradeCode, ...

Comment: @Vasiliy:

I am changing the ProductCode, UpgradeCode and ProductName.

At the same time I also insert some new bespoke properties but those are just used for configuring the software at install time.

Comment: I assume you need also change PackageCode. As it must be different for each .msi package. Try it.

Comment: When you say PackageCode, do you mean the 'Revision' (0x9) in the Summary Information stream?

If so, yes - we are changing that as well.

Comment: Nope. Just open .vdproj with notepad and search for `PackageCode` text.

Comment: @Vasiliy: Do you know where abouts in Orca this PackageCode field can be found?

Comment: The package code is stored in the Revision Number Summary Property of the Summary Information Stream. ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370568(VS.85).aspx )

you can access and modify it by using the summary information screen in Orca.exe ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/465253cd.aspx )

That is all I know.

Comment: Seems like you already changing it...

I have a question. Why can't you create two vdproj projects one for Acme and second one for Zurg?

Comment: Vasiliy: As I said, we are updating that field.

I just found this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/d48d44a4-3deb-4753-94f8-a94503510a06

It appears to be the identical problem. Maybe I am going about this in entirely the wrong way. It would appear the MSI doesn't want to install duplicates of the files

Comment: Vasiliy: We need to create true instancing support. This is not something we can engineer into our Build process because at build-time we don't know what instances there need to be.

Creating two VDPROJ's with 99% identical content violates the DRY principle also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is can be considered a hack, but it solves the issue. Of course there will be ramifications for MSI's that you intend to issue patches or upgrades for. But for our particular scenario this is not an issue because an upgrade will always involve uninstalling the server and then reinstalling it using the newer MSI.

Anyway, the workaround is this:-

Use Orca to look at your MSI. Go into the table called `Component`. In this table is a column called `ComponentId`. The values for all of these must be updated to have a new value (a fresh GUID). None of the other columns matter, the `Component` column which has a `C__` prefix is only used internally by the MSI database. The critical one, as explained, is the `ComponentId` because this is the one that gets stored (albeit in some hashed/encrypted form) in the Windows Registry and is used by MSI to keep reference counters.

More detail on this `ComponentId` column is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368007(VS.85).aspx

To automate this, I am going to improve our "Instance MSI Generator" utility to basically generate a new GUID for each record in the `Component` table.